# How can I tell whether chrome.proxy.settings.set is correctly setting my proxies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Google Chrome Extension, my `popup.js` includes:

```
function setProxyToUse() {
  var enable = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      proxyForHttps: {host: localStorage["surveyHTTPS"]},
      proxyForHttp: {host: localStorage["surveyHTTP"]}
    }
  };
  var disable = {mode: "system"}
  if (localStorage["proxyOn"] == true) {var config = enable} else {var config = disable}
  chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: 'regular'},function() {});
  chrome.proxy.settings.get({}, function(config) {console.log(config.value.host);} ); 
}
```

The last line simply writes `undefined` to the console. How can I check which proxy host I'm using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default proxy value is a string `"system"` which doesn't have the property you're trying to display (`.host`).

If you want to read the value you've just set, do it in the callback of `.set` because chrome API is asynchronous:

```
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: 'regular'}, function() {
    chrome.proxy.settings.get({}, function(config) {
        console.log(config.value, config.value.host);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Using a variant of this, I can now see that my function is applying the correct version of config. However, I still can't independently see what proxy Chrome is using for each web request. I might raise that as a separate question.